# Error after installing jetty plugin for WebStorm

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetty, jetty-9

I am using `jetty server` in WebStorm. I installed this this plugin using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>.

> A plugin that allows you to quickly run Jetty from IntelliJ IDEA.  If you require full support please consider buying the IntelliJ IDEA Enterprise Edition. This plugin should be Win / Mac / Linux compatible.  Compatible with servlet-api versions: 3.1, 3.0, 2.5, 2.4, 2.3, 2.2. Many thanks for the kind contributions on GitHub, cheers guys!  Minimum requirement: JVM / JDK / JRE v7 tags: jetty, container, webapp, runner, tomcat, runner
>       Change Notes
>       Head over to GitHub to see the latest change notes and learn more about this plugin. Thanks for dropping by.
>       Vendor
>       IntelliJ Jetty Runner

**After install I am getting this error**

```
 com/intellij/openapi/compiler/CompileScope
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/openapi/compiler/CompileScope
            at com.github.guikeller.jettyrunner.model.JettyRunnerConfiguration.getConfigurationEditor(JettyRunnerConfiguration.java:65)
            at com.intellij.execution.impl.ConfigurationSettingsEditor.<init>(ConfigurationSettingsEditor.java:220)
            at com.intellij.execution.impl.ConfigurationSettingsEditorWrapper.<init>(ConfigurationSettingsEditorWrapper.java:67)
            at com.intellij.execution.impl.TemplateConfigurable.<init>(TemplateConfigurable.java:29)
            at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunConfigurable.a(RunConfigurable.java:344)
            at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunConfigurable.access$1000(RunConfigurable.java:70)
            at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunConfigurable$4.valueChanged(RunConfigurable.java:274)
            at javax.swing.JTree.fireValueChanged(JTree.java:2926)
            at javax.swing.JTree$TreeSelectionRedirector.valueChanged(JTree.java:3387)
            at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:635)
            at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.Tree$MySelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Tree.java:643)
            at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.notifyPathChange(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:1093)
            at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPaths(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:294)
            at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPath(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:188)
            at javax.swing.JTree.setSelectionPath(JTree.java:1633)
            at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.selectPathForEvent(BasicTreeUI.java:2393)
            at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.handleSelection(BasicTreeUI.java:3609)
            at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.mousePressedDND(BasicTreeUI.java:3586)
            at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTreeUI.java:3545)
            at com.intellij.util.ui.MouseEventAdapter.mousePressed(MouseEventAdapter.java:41)
            at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:279)
            at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:279)
            at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:279)
            at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:279)
            at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6522)
            at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
            at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.Tree.processMouseEvent(Tree.java:410)
            at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
            at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
            at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
            at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
            at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
            at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
            at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4530)
            at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
            at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
            at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
            at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
            at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
            at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.g(IdeEventQueue.java:866)
            at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
            at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
            at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
            at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
            at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
            at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
            at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:792)
            at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:465)
            at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1638)
            at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1587)
            at com.intellij.execution.actions.EditRunConfigurationsAction.actionPerformed(EditRunConfigurationsAction.java:49)
            at com.intellij.ui.popup.PopupFactoryImpl$ActionPopupStep.performAction(PopupFactoryImpl.java:856)
            at com.intellij.ui.popup.PopupFactoryImpl$ActionPopupStep$1.run(PopupFactoryImpl.java:842)
            at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
            at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.g(IdeEventQueue.java:866)
            at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:654)
            at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.openapi.compiler.CompileScope PluginClassLoader[JettyRunner-GK, 1.1.3]
            at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:68)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            ... 86 more
```

Answer (score 0):

We are currently investigating the plugin's compatibility with WebStorm. 
https://github.com/guikeller/jetty-runner/issues/23

I will add this StackOverflow thread as part of the issue there as well.
Also, an issue has been raised with JetBrains and they're looking into it.

Thanks for getting in touch with me.

Cheers, Gui

Comment: That's something that I would like to know too; all that I know is that JetBrains is looking into it and they'll update me with their progress. For now keep an eye on the issue on GitHub, cheers!